# Inserting new row in tableview duplicates last row

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

When I'm inserting a new row using `tableView.insertRows`, for some reason, sometimes it inserts a new row which is a duplicate of the last row, while sometimes it works as expected by inserting the newly added row. I'm really confused... what I'm doing wrong?

```
var list: Results<Item>?
var selectedCategory: Category = Category()
```

selectedCategory value will be set in the pervious view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    list = selectedCategory.items.sorted(byKeyPath: "title")
}
```

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)
        if let item = list?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
            cell.accessoryType = item.done ? .checkmark : .none
        }
        return cell
    }
```

```
    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let newItem = Item()
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New To Do", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { item in
            textField = item
        }
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { action in
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            try! self.realm.write {
                self.selectedCategory.items.append(newItem)
                self.realm.add(newItem)
            }
            let pos = self.list!.count-1
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: pos , section: 0)], with: .left)
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cell class, add the prepareForReuse () method and clear the cell contents. Should help.

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)